# How to have PXE boot try forever to boot?

Tags: boot, pxe

Sorry for asking maybe a stupid question, but I'm kind of stuck. I have configured my system to boot from network (PXE boot), but now I want to check that it keeps trying to boot even if the dhcp server is not available.
Unfortunately my system keeps trying for a while, then it stops displaying the following message:

```
PXE-E51 No DHCP or proxy DHCP offers were found or received
Reboot and select proper media device or insert boot media in selected 
boot device and press a key
```

And after that it stops trying.
What I would like to achieve is a situation where it continuously keeps trying so that as soon as the DHCP server becomes available it will be able to boot.

The problem is that I don't know which configuration I need to modify. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That would all depend on your network card's option ROM; you can't just run different software to change PxE boot behavior. Most of the time you can get to these settings from the BIOS / UEFI config menu, but you should consult your motherboard's or NIC card's documentation to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved the problem by adding a USB stick to my board that basically was just rebooting the system. I selected this USB stick as second boot option and implemented a continuous boot this way.
I couldn't find an option to set this from the BIOS.